# OpenJDK 8 support period in Debian Stretch 9

Tags: debian, security, java, software-updates, openjdk

According to the [Debian releases page](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases#Production_Releases) Stretch 9 has support until ~2022. What does this mean for the [OpenJDK 8 package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=openjdk-8&searchon=names&suite=stretch&section=all)?

How long will security updates be available for OpenJDK 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security updates will be available for OpenJDK 8 for as long as Red Hat continues to provide them (since Red Hat is the official maintainer of OpenJDK 8 now); that’s supposed to be until [June 2023](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1299013), which covers the Debian 9 support period.